# Need to add the value of two spinners and populate in edit text

Tags: android, spinner

I am having a hard time getting a spinner to populate a value. I have two spinners, each have multiple items to choose from. They need to be added together and populate in a edit text box.

I also have a discount % edit text where the user will enter a discount. The total of the two spinners needs to be discount by the amount entered in this box.

Could anyone help me with this. I am currently not at my computer that I am programming with so I can not paste the code i currently have but for this example could you just use, spinner "A", spinner "B", Edit text "cost", Edit text "discount"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly is the problem? can you not get the selected spinner values?

pls see the spinner example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) as well as the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html). especially look for setOnItemSelectedListener().

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of this:

```
int subtotal = Integer.parseInt((String) spinnerA.getSelectedItem()) * Integer.parseInt((String) spinnerB.getSelectedItem());
double discount = Double.parseDouble(discountEditText.getText().toString()) / 100;

double total = subtotal * (1.0 - discount);
```

(This assumes that you have ensured the discount field is a valid Double and expects an input like `10`%.)